# nVidia CUDA installation does not detect GTX 970

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I installed a brand new GTX 970 from Gigabyte in my system and it basically works so far. However I need CUDA and when I ran the CUDA 6.5 driver installation, it said:

> This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware. You may continue installation, but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.

The GTX 970 officially supports CUDA.

[image: GPU-Z screenshot]

**PC-specs:**

```
 Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1
 System Model: GA-970A-DS3
 BIOS: Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
 Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor (8 CPUs), ~3.6GHz
 Memory: 16384MB RAM
 Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
 Chip type: GeForce GTX 970
 DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
 Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2&SUBSYS_366A1458&REV_A1
 Display Memory: 4095 MB
 Dedicated Memory: 3072 MB
 Shared Memory: 1023 MB
 Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
 Monitor Name: PnP-Monitor (Standard)
 Monitor Model: Viseo243D
 Monitor Id: PKB0386
 Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)
 Output Type: HDMI
 Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
 Driver File Version: 9.18.0013.4752 (English)
 Driver Version: 9.18.13.4752
 DDI Version: 11
 Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
 Driver Attributes: Final Retail
 Driver Date/Size: 3/2/2015 20:13:36, 17253848 bytes
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the same card.
I tried it with the new special CUDA 6.5 version but the error occurs again.
absolutely none of the programs planned for operation in GPU mode does not work.
3ds Max ,Rhino 5... If anyone has a solution ,please help me. thank you in advance.
Maxa.

Comment: @Maxa try the new CUDA 7: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download [this special version of CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx) to support the new Geforce GTX 9XX cards.

> **Q:** How does this release differ from the current CUDA 6.5 Release?
>
> **A:** **This toolkit contain support for th**e GeForce GTX980 and **GTX970**. In
>   addition, driver support for older generation GPUs with SM1.x has been
>   deprecated.